# How do I select values of 2 key-value pairs where the dates are the same?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, datetime, select

So what I want to only display 2 key value pairs if their dates are the same. So for example if a key-value pair doesn't have the exact same date-time as another key value pair, then don't show them at all...

So my logic is as follows, but I dont know how to implement it:

```
SELECT ForeignKeyID, Value, Date
  FROM tblMyTable
//declare myDate= null ????
  where (ForeignKeyID = 1 and Value > 14) or (ForeignKeyID = 2 and Value > 10)
//somehow check if myDate from the first key-value pair has the exact same myDate as the second one or vice versa.
```

Here is what I want and don't want to display:

```
Time                    ForeignKeyID Value
2015-05-27 00:30:00.000     1       15.000 //Yes because same date for 2 exists
2015-05-27 00:30:00.000     2       13.800 //Yes because same date for 1 exists
2015-05-27 00:45:00.000     1       15.000 //Yes
2015-05-27 00:45:00.000     2       13.800 //Yes
2015-05-27 01:00:00.000     1       15.000 //Yes
2015-05-27 01:00:00.000     2       13.300 //Yes
2015-05-27 01:15:00.000     1       15.000 //Yes
2015-05-27 01:15:00.000     2       13.300 //Yes
2015-05-27 01:30:00.000     2       13.300 //No because the same date for 1 doesnt exist!
2015-05-27 01:45:00.000     2       13.300 //No because the same date for 1 doesnt exist!
2015-05-27 02:00:00.000     1       15.000 //No because the same date for 2 doesnt exist!
2015-05-27 02:15:00.000     1       15.000 //No because the same date for 2 doesnt exist!
```

Really sorry for my ignorance here but I'm trying to learn here...

Comment: Google and learn about the `WHERE EXISTS()` function in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, a self-join might be easiest:

```
select t1.ForeignKeyID, t1.Value, t1.Date,
       t2.ForeignKeyID, t2.Value, t2.Date
from tblMyTable t1 join
     tblMyTable t2
     on t1.ForeignKeyID = 1 and t1.value > 14 and
        t2.ForeignKeyID = 2 and t2.value > 10 and
        t1.date = t2.date;
```

This does put the matching values in one row rather than two rows.

EDIT:

If you want two rows, you can  use complicated `exists` logic:

```
select t.ForeignKeyID, t.Value, t.Date
from tblMyTable t
where (t.ForeignKeyID = 1 and t.value > 14 and
       exists (select 1
               from tblMyTable t2
               where t2.ForeignKeyID = 2 and t2.value > 10 and t2.date = t.date
              )
      ) or
      (t.ForeignKeyID = 2 and t.value > 10 and
       exists (select 1
               from tblMyTable t2
               where t2.ForeignKeyID = 1 and t2.value > 14 and t2.date = t.date
              )
      );
```

I think the first version is probably more useful.

Or, a simpler way is to use window functions:

```
select t.ForeignKeyID, t.Value, t.Date
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when ForeignKeyID = 1 and value > 14 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by date) as cnt1,
             sum(case when ForeignKeyID = 2 and value > 10 then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by date) as cnt2
      from mytable t
      where (ForeignKeyID = 1 and Value > 14) or (ForeignKeyID = 2 and Value > 10)
     ) t
where cnt1 > 0 and cnt2 > 0
```

Comment: I pressed execute query 3 mins ago and its still processing, the weird thing is that it does it almost instantly when I do it without the date constraints...

Comment: So the first one is still executing for the past 15 mins. As for the second one (the exists logic) gives me an empty result which I know is not possible because I took the example from that table...

As for the third one, Im not sure what it is supposed to do?

Comment: @Vrankela . . . You must have a large amount of data.  It is not clear why the second would return an empty result set.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the analytic function COUNT OVER to see how many keys you get per date:

```
select foreignkeyid, value, date
from
(
  select 
    foreignkeyid, 
    value, 
    date, 
    count(distinct foreignkeyid) over (partition by date) as cnt
  from tblmytable
  where (foreignkeyid = 1 and value > 14) or (foreignkeyid = 2 and value > 10)
) counted
where cnt = 2
order by date, foreignkeyid;
```